# Youtube-DL Search Return URL of Video

Tags: python, youtube-dl

So I want to search a Youtube Video with the ytsearch function of youtube-dl and give out the url of the found video and store it in a variable. Is there an option to do that in Python?

As an example, how would I get the url from the code below?

```
async def play(ctx):
args = ctx.message.content.split(" ")
os.system('youtube-dl --get-url "ytsearch:{}"'.format(args[1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work but if you are running windows you can add > filename.txt to the end of your os argument to make an output of the cmd command.

```
async def play(ctx):
args = ctx.message.content.split(" ")
os.system('youtube-dl --get-url "ytsearch:{}"'.format(args[1])+ "> filename.txt")
```

Then you can read the file and store that result in a variable by writing...

```
file = open("filename.txt","r")
output = file.read()
file.close()
```

Im assuming that whatever the output of the command is would be the url?